# Replacement for mailto: Extension?

Tags: email, chrome

I've  been using the 'mailto' google chrome extension for years. It allows -- or rather allowed -- me to right click on a page and choose a menu option to email the URL. Fine and dandy. Today I went to do this; the menu option was gone, and drilling into the extensions showed that it was marked with

> This extension violates the Chrome Web Store policy.

*SIGH.*

Well. OK. Maybe they were doing something wrong, maybe they weren't. At this point, I'll never know... but I want a replacement.

### I've got four criteria:

#### Non negotiable:

- Secure -- won't spy on me, uses secure protocols
- Cross platform

#### Nice to have:

- Choose account / email provider
- Mature, won't get removed by Chrome web store.

### So far, I've looked at the following

Everything was marked as 'works on your device' (composed on XUbuntu), so cross platform support seems ok...

- [Mailto: for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailto-for-gmail/dgkkmcknielgdhebimdnfahpipajcpjn) -- this seems to be pretty much a drop in replacement for what I've been using. Their [privacy policy](http://ilikesleeping.co.uk/mailto-privacy-policy/) makes the right noises. It's got 100K users. That doesn't guarantee that it isn't going anywhere, but it's a good sign... but it seems like it's gmail only, and doesn't seem to have the ability to switch accounts.
- [mailto](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailto/nhfdmebpfpogeakgjmgbalpnmggnnchj) -- Looks like it might support email providers other than gmail, but there's *nothing* to go on in the privacy policy page. I'm not sure if they're being honest about not giving me any privacy or just inexperienced, but I'm giving this one a pass.
- [Send from Gmail (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-from-gmail-by-google/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc). Looks pretty similar to the first one on the list, but no privacy policy. Et tu Google?? Pass.
- [Share link via email](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-link-via-email/ejdbkikfbnnhmachnnomjfgjbgkcnjkb). This looks promising -- It's got 80K users, the reviews aren't filled with hate, and it seems to support multiple email providers. Not sure if it allows me to choose account on the fly ... but no privacy policy.

There are a bajillion other plugins to choose from, but of course who knows how well they're supported, what their privacy policies are, whether they're being truthful about those. Anyone using a mailto plugin that they like and trust? Anything that has the ability to choose email accounts with a minimal amount of friction?

Comment: You don't actually need it to be cross-platform, the functionality is already built-in to macOS. In Chrome it's File menu > Share >[several options] but Email Link is already hot-keyed as Cmd/Shift/i [although in Safari it's just Cmd/i so it's not consistent though you could change it in keyboard prefs].

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if I'm on macOS, but the platforms I'm using are Linux and Windows.